# Expandable List View getChildrenCount returns null

Tags: android, expandablelistadapter

I'm trying to implement an Expandable list view, I've set it up correctly and it displays the correct headers, but the inner items are not being shown because getChildrenCount() always returns null, here's my code:

```
/**
 * Created by Ahmed on 2/21/2015.
 */
public class CompaniesAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private ExpandableListView list;
    private Context context;
    private HashMap<Category, ArrayList<Company>> companies;

    public CompaniesAdapter(Context context, HashMap<Category, ArrayList<Company>> companies, ExpandableListView list) {
        this.list = list;
        this.context = context;
        this.companies = companies;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return companies.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        ArrayList<Company> x = companies.get(0);
        Log.v("", "" + x.size());
        return companies.get(groupPosition).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return companies.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return companies.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        Set<Category> category = companies.keySet();
        Object[] s =  category.toArray();
        Category cat = (Category) s[groupPosition];
        String title = cat.getTitle();
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.company_header_item, null);
        }

        TextView titleTxt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.companiesHeaderItem);
        titleTxt.setText(title);
        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.companies_list_item, null);
        }

        ImageView companyLogo = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.companyLogo);
        Picasso.with(context).load(companies.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).getImgLink()).into(companyLogo);

        TextView companyName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.companyName);
        TextView companyArName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.companyArName);

        if (Utils.getDefaultLang(context) == Const.ARABIC) {
            companyName.setText(companies.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).getArTitle());
            companyArName.setText(companies.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).getTitle());
        } else {
            companyArName.setText(companies.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).getArTitle());
            companyName.setText(companies.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition).getTitle());
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }`
}
```

Comment: Can you post your activity/fragment code where you populate the list?

Comment: Are you modifying the map companies somewhere outside of the adapter?

Comment: No, once it's sent to the adapter it's not modified, the getGroupView() method works just fine. The getChiledView() doesn't however, the count always returns wrong so no data is populated.